rsync: out of memory (code 22) error when transfering a huge file
I'm trying to use rsync to sync up a directory to a remote server, it has some very large files, a few of them over 1Tb. The remote server has a very outdated version of the same dir.
The command:
rsync -avz /path/to/dir/ [remote]:/path/to/dir/
Throws this error:
ERROR: out of memory in receive_sums [sender]
rsync error: error allocating core memory buffers (code 22) at util.c(117) [sender=3.0.6]

When encountering one of the really large files (in this case ~4.5T)
How do I fix this? I am ok with not using rsync delta algorithm (if that is why this happens) if it means sacrificing speed, as this is one-time operation.
If it matters, the local server is an older Gentoo server and has 32G of memory.
I'm also open to other suggestions as to how to transfer really large files over local network using simple linux tools, I cannot use third party installs.

Do you have swap space, or a swap partition? free will tell you. Does your system support swap files? Read man mkswap fallocate filefrag.

It does have swap space but its pretty small, about 2G compared to 32G of memory loaded. I can create a swap file in this OS but im not sure how big of a memory allocation rsync needs for this transfer

The option -W or --whole-file will disable the delta algorithm. If you have sparse files add -S to preserve them, and -H to preserve hard links.

Removing the -z option can also good idea unless the network between the two servers is very slow.  If the network path is faster than 100 Mbps, I've usually found compression makes the transfer throughput slower rather than faster.  This won't help the memory consumption problem, but may help the speed.

Start with the size of the biggest file * 1.2, try 1 x RAM, or even 2 x RAM.
One uses swap space to control what happens when programs allocate all the real memory, and want more. After all releasable cache (some cached blocks are "in use", and cannot be freed) has been released, the system enters the Out-Of-Memory state. In the Out-Of-Memory condition, with swap, some task's memory is written to disk, freed for reuse, and later  returned to memory (swapped in) when the task runs. Without swap, the system may freeze,  the dreaded OOM-Killer (a pseudo process, hard-coded in the kernel) runs, and picks a process to KILL, in order to free memory. The OOM-Killer is known for inconvenient choices.
System hibernation requires a RAM-sized, contiguous swap area.
Read man mkswap fallocate  filefrag swapon fstab.
